# how to use $inc, $addfields inside $set in updatingr inserting a document in mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with documents in below format

```
      {"_id": {"$oid": "6389fe414b13037521582cbb"},
       "name": "Ann",
       "version": 1,
       "amount_paid": 1000,
       "createDate": 2022-12-02T13:31:45.416+00:00
       "studentId": 111,
       "purchased": [
                     {
                       "item_name": "notebooks",
                       "price": 300
                     },
                     {
                       "item_name": "textbooks",
                       "price": 700
                     }
                    ]
      }
```

amount paid is the sum of `purchased.price`.
I am trying to update the document, if `studentId` not present it should insert the new document. if the document is getting updated the version should change from `1` to `2`, if creating new version should be `1`.

What I tried is

```
      db.students.update_one({
          'studentId': 111},
        {
          '$set': {
            "name":"Ann", 
            "version":{"$inc": { "version": 1 }},
            "purchased":[{"item_name":"notebooks","price":500}, 
                         {"item_name":"uniform","price":500}],
          "$addFields" : {
            "amount_paid" : {"$sum" : "$purchased.price"}},
            "createDate":datetime.datetime.now(),,
          }
        }
     ,upsert=true)
```

but this is giving me an error

```
WriteError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$addFields' in
'$addFields' is not allowed in the context of an update's
replacement document. Consider using an aggregation pipeline
with $replaceWith.,
full error: {'index': 0, 'code': 52, 'errmsg': "The dollar ($) prefixed field '$addFields' in '$addFields' is not allowed in the context of an update's replacement document. Consider using an aggregation pipeline with $replaceWith."}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/). This allows you to perform a sum of the field value in the document.

While the `$set` stage will add a field if the field does not exist as long the value is provided (not `null` or `undefined`), hence the `$addFields` stage is not needed.

```
db.collection.update({
  "studentId": 111
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "name": "Ann",
      "version": {
        "$sum": [
          "$version",
          1
        ]
      },
      "purchased": [
        {
          "item_name": "notebooks",
          "price": 500
        },
        {
          "item_name": "uniform",
          "price": 500
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "amount_paid": {
        "$sum": "$purchased.price"
      },
      created_date: new Date()
    }
  }
],
{
  upsert: true
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TSM-fs8f2u3)

Comment: I messed up an edit on the OP's question - I reverted and did less editing.  Please see reverted/updated question.  Also, won't `"amount_paid": {"$sum": "$purchased.price"}` need to be in another stage in case there is an `upsert`?

Comment: when creating a new document, $sum is not working, its giving 0 as amount_paid @Yong

Comment: @Mila, done update answer, only perform sum for `amount_paid` after the `purchased` array is upserted with items.